# Need help to understand the Flat Map execution for mentioned code sample

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to call a rest api & accumulating result by using Flux & Webclient.
I want to understand the execution of flatMap operator for below code.

- **list** - Contains 50000 element.
- **restClient** - It is a WebClient. `WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions.basicAuthentication(userId, pwd)).build()`
- **restClient.getResult** - return a Mono. `client.get().uri(uri).retrieve().bodyToMono(returnType)`

First log is printing thread name as main for certain no. of element then it started to print reactor-http-nio-(thread-no).
Second log is printing thread name as reactor-http-nio-(thread-no).
Pls explain how does the thread execution & switching is happening here.

```
        Flux.fromIterable(list)
            .log()
            .map(e -> e.trim())
            .flatMap(e -> restClient.getResult(client, e, String.class))//e is being used to create uri
            .log()
            .subscribe(e -> result.add(e));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap` has a `concurrency` parameter, which defaults to 256.
As soon as it is subscribed, it requests 256 elements from the source (the `fromIterable`) and maps them to inner publishers (the `WebClient` calls).

This is done in the subscription thread, which here is the `main` thread.

Once it has 256 elements "in flight", `flatMap` will replenish as needed whenever an inner completes, by requesting one more source element from the iterable, then mapping it to a new `WebClient` inner.

This is done in the thread of the inner that just finished, which here is the netty `http-nio-x` thread.